# How To Send Data From One Page To Another Such That Page Do Not Navigate C# Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to navigate only data from one page to another i am using this code to navigate data to another page that is,

```
FROM FIRST PAGE
Response.Redirect("testing.aspx?Parameter=" + txtCommission.Text);

To SECOND PAGE
txtCommission.Text = Request.QueryString["Parameter"].ToString();
```

but by using this code i am also navite to another page while i want to just send data to the Second page when i check check box??

hopes for your suggestions..

Comment: Is the second page already open somewhere? Otherwise it would not be possible to send any data to it without opening it.

Comment: No it is Not Opened any where !

Comment: page is not loaded into browser and still you want to push some data? is that whats been asked here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible. If the page isn't open anywhere, then you can't send any data to it without opening it.

The server code that produces a page only runs when the page is requested, the rest of the time the code is not active and there is no `Page` instance for the page.

If the page would be open in another window, you could access the page using Javascript as long as you have a reference to it (which you only have in the code that has opened that window), or if that page has opened the current page so that you can use `window.opener` or `window.parent` to get the reference to it.